# How do I go to sleep?

Tags: stardew-valley

Apologies for the simple question but I just can't seem to do it.

I wait until night time, go to my bed in my house, and click x, left click, right click, click every damn key, and I just stand there...

I've missed something really obvious right?

Comment: Try some Ambien.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a [Steam Forum](http://steamcommunity.com/app/413150/discussions/0/405692758718229019/), some users indicate that directly "colliding" with the bed or "walking into it" is usually the way it works:

> Go to sleep (tool in hand and run on bed, if you have item over your head, it wont sleep) before 2AM or you will faint, get doctors bill and little energy. Also eating foods give energy, just read tooltip!

---

> You walk into the far side of the bed to sleep. You can eat crops and food to heal and restore energy. It tells you how much it will restore with a green + for energy and red for health.

Comment: oh wow I had just not walked far enough to the FAR SIDE I guess. Sigh, thank you SO much!